# Install Windows 10 on an EFI / hybrid MBR Macbook?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, macbook, mbr, efi

I have an 2011 macbook which has been updated to EFI 1.7.

Bootcamp sets up a hybrid MBR to support Windows 7.

I need to install Windows 10 on this hybrid MBR setup instead of an EFI/GPT setup because the Cirrus audio chip doesn't register itself on an EFI/GPT setup for whatever reason.

The **problem** is that Windows 10 *prefers* (U)EFI GPT hard disks and refuses to install on a hybrid MBR citing that it can't install on an MBR partition in an EFI system.

How can I force Windows 10 to install on a hybrid MBR setup and bypass the EFI/MBR error it gives upon install?

Comment: Enable Legacy mode and boot to the installation media.  [Windows on a hybrid MBR/GPT](http://superuser.com/questions/297776/windows-on-a-hybrid-mbr-gpt?rq=1).  The answers to those questions still apply to Windows 10, nothing, has change since those answers were submitted.

Comment: If you're not trying to triple-boot with something that boots only in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, you might do better to convert the hybrid MBR to a legal protective MBR and install Windows in EFI mode. You can do the hybrid-to-protective conversion by re-writing the protective MBR area. Some tools, like libparted in Linux, do this automatically whenever you make any trivial change. My own [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk) will do this if you type `x` followed by `n` at its menus. (You must also type `w` to save this change.)